# How to hyphenate "corned beef filled"?

Tags: hyphenation

"Tuna-filled" is hyphenated correctly, right?

If we were to fill something with "corned beef", how would we write "corned beef filled"? Where would the hyphen go?

Comment: World's worst dumplings.

Comment: Firstly, I don't see why this was closed. It seems like a reasonable question to me.  Secondly, I'd avoid the problem altogether by saying 'with a corned beef filling' or similar. And thirdly, Andy, corned beef dumplings don't sound at all bad. What do you see as wrong with them.

Answer (score 1):

The *Chicago Manual of Style* would recommend *corned beef–filled*, with an en dash, not a hyphen. Section 6.80 of the 17th edition:

> The en dash can be used in place of a hyphen in a compound adjective when one of its elements consists of an open compound or when both elements consist of hyphenated compounds (see 7.82). Whereas a hyphen joins exactly two words, the en dash is intended to signal a link across more than two. Because this editorial nicety will certainly go unnoticed by the majority of readers, it should be used sparingly, when a more elegant solution is unavailable.

*CMOS* provides *country music–influenced lyrics* as an example but also suggests the rephrasing *lyrics influenced by country music*, because "the relationship [...] depends to some small degree on an en dash that many readers will perceive as a hyphen connecting *music* and *influenced*."

Comment: That looks like a particularly ugly and misleading solution. The reader immediately percevies a hyphen rather than an en dash. This leads to understanding someting is filled with beef and that is what's "corned". We don't read letters and words strictly  left to right, but rather take in many  features, including word shapes, between eye saccades. I would leave out hyphens or opt for corned-beef filled.